# First li's same height?

Tags: html, jquery, css, height, html-lists

I have an ul menu with li's:

Here the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uvkQp/

There are 3 Top item li's on every row then the subitems under it and then again 3 Top items with subitems under it. How can i get that the Top item li's are even in height everytime (biggest hight with the most Subitems inside it).

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
         <a href="#">Top item</a>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
         <a href="#">Top item</a>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
         <a href="#">Top item</a>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
         <a href="#">Top item</a>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
         <a href="#">Top item</a>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#content{
float : left;
position : relative;
overflow : hidden;
padding : 0 28px 0 0;
width : 728px;
}

ul.menu,
ul.menu ul{
display : inline-block;
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
list-style : none;
width : 100%;
}

ul.menu li{
float : left;
font : 17px/1.0em open_sansbold;
margin : 0 0 0 28px;
color : #2780af;
text-transform : uppercase;
width : 224px;
}

ul.menu li:first-child,
ul.menu li:first-child + li + li + li + li {
margin : 0;
}

ul.menu li li{
font : 12px/1.0em open_sansregular;
margin : 0;
padding : 5px 0;
color : #777777;
text-transform : normal;
}

ul.menu li a, ul.menu li a:link, ul.menu li a:active, ul.menu li a:visited, ul.menu li a:hover {
display : block;
background : url(gfx/line-dotted.gif) repeat-x left bottom #FFFFFF;
margin : 0 0 5px;
padding : 0 0 11px;
color : #2780af;
text-decoration : none;
cursor : text;
}

ul.menu li li a, ul.menu li li a:link, ul.menu li li a:active, ul.menu li li a:visited {
display : block;
background : #FFFFFF;
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
color : #777777;
text-decoration : underline;
cursor : pointer;
}

ul.menu li li a:hover {
color : #000000;
text-decoration : none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find the fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/aBUhJ/

Here is the code

```
$(function(){
    maxH=0;
    $('.menu > li').each(function(){
        maxH = $(this).height() > maxH ? $(this).height() : maxH;
    })
    $('.menu > li').height(maxH);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
$("ul.menu > li:nth-child(3n+1)").css("clear","both");
```